# Perfect Forwarding to a Private Class Constructor Through a Templated Friend Class

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, perfect-forwarding

I'm exploring usage of the `friend` keyword with variadic templates, perfect forwarding, and private constructors. I feel like I'm missing something fundamental about all of this, because the following simple example won't compile.

I want `Test_Manager<Test_Class>::Process` to be the only way to construct an object of type `Test_Class` (`Process` will eventually do more but this is a trivial example). I also want `Test_Manager` to be able to 'manage' various classes in this way, hence the argument `t_Symbol` for the class type, and the variadic `...t_Args` to handle various constructors.

```
// Test.cpp
#include <string>

template<typename t_Symbol>
struct Test_Manager
{
    template<typename... t_Args>
    static t_Symbol Process(const t_Args&... i_Args)
    {
        const t_Symbol New_Symbol(std::forward<t_Args>(i_Args)...); // error C2665

        return New_Symbol;
    }
};

class Test_Class
{
    private:

        friend Test_Manager<Test_Class>;

        Test_Class() {};
        Test_Class(const std::string& i_Text) : m_Text(i_Text) {};

        const std::string m_Text;
};

void Test_Function()
{
    std::string text = "hello_world";

    Test_Class t = Test_Manager<Test_Class>::Process(text);
}
```

However with Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 I get the following error (at the line marked above): `error C2665: 'std::forward': none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types`. What am I screwing up here? I feel like this should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I screwing up here?

Yes, you are. In the code below:

```
template<typename... t_Args>
static t_Symbol Process(const t_Args&... i_Args){
    const t_Symbol New_Symbol(std::forward<t_Args>(i_Args)...);
    ...
}
```

The problem above is that `i_Args` will have a `const` qualification but you told [`std::forward`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) `std::forward<t_Arg>` you will send a `t_Arg` type, which doesn't carry a `const` qualification.

So, essentially, the problem with your `std::forward<t_Args>(i_Arg)` is that the *Type* `t_Args`, doesn't carry an implicit `const`, but the *Argument* `i_Arg`, has a `const`.

You should use `std::forward` on forwarding references. When you do, `t_Arg` will implicitly carry the necessary *cv* qualification, which will match the *cv* qualifications of the `i_Arg`

You want to change it to:

```
template<typename... t_Args>
static t_Symbol Process(t_Args&&... i_Args){
    ...
}
```

---

EDIT, As per Guillaume Racicot's comment:

When you try to *move* a value into `Process`, for example:

```
Test_Manager<Test_Class>::Process(std::move(text));
```

The constructor of `Test_Class` will defeat the `std::forward` because it's still going to make a copy as per.

```
Test_Class(const std::string& i_Text) : m_Text(i_Text) {};
```

However, when the constructor is defined as:

```
Test_Class(std::string i_Text) : m_Text(std::move(i_Text)) {};
```

No copy will be made, only moves.

Comment: maybe mention that `Test_Class` should take the string by value and move it to the member instead of copying it.

Comment: Can you please go into a little more detail why the first constructor makes a copy/defeats std::forward?

Answer (score 1):

`std::forward` is meant for use with forwarding references (or universal references), which is a `T&&` function parameter where `T` is a template parameter.  Perfect forwarding would look like:

```
template<typename... t_Args>
static t_Symbol Process(t_Args&&... i_Args)
{
    t_Symbol New_Symbol(std::forward<t_Args>(i_Args)...);

    return New_Symbol;
}
```

If you want `Process` to only take `const` lvalues, that's okay, but then don't use `std::forward`:

```
template<typename... t_Args>
static t_Symbol Process(const t_Args&... i_Args)
{
    t_Symbol New_Symbol(i_Args...);

    return New_Symbol;
}
```

Comment: Ah... so because of the move semantics involved in std::forward, its arguments can't be const lvalues?

Comment: The argument can be a const lvalue as long as the template argument is also const.  In your example, `t_Args` was `std::string` but `i_Args` was `const std::string&`.